# Using git with synced files with different Windows usernames

Tags: git

For a particular git repository, I'm using a OneDrive account to keep two Windows 10 machines synced, let's say `MachineA` and `MachineB`.  Yes I could do the push/pull/merge dance between the two machines, so please don't recommend that.  I'm asking about a specific off-label usage of git.  I do this because I switch very often when coding at home (back and forth between desk and sofa, depending on kid, wife, dinnertime), and because I don't want to commit half-written code or pollute my history with a zillion trivial commits.

Beyond Compare tells me the files are binary-same, but although I can edit the files and execute my project, I cannot run any git commands on the machine opposite from where the repo was created.  Somehow the username is captured in the repository.

For instance, if I had created the repo on MachineA with usernameA, then run *any* git command on MachineB (having usernameB), I get:

```
$ git status
fatal: Invalid path 'c:/Users/usernameA': No such file or directory
```

This failure happens in both directions, depending on where the git repo was created.  Git works fine elsewhere on each machine independently, but does not work on the other machine.  I'm using using git 2.18.0.windows.1 on one machine and and 2.17.1.windows2 on the other.

I could not find a hard-coded username or user home directory in any human-readable config setting -- global, system, or local to the repo.

I can replicate the problem with a fresh repository, with no files or commits -- just a `git init`.

If this is a fundamentally not workable usage of git, then I'll change my habits.

If, technically speaking, a binary-same git directory should work on a machine different from where it was created, I'd like to know how to fix this.

Comment: Are u using the same paths on both machines? One Drive store an internal settings as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and because I don't want to commit half-written code or pollute my history with a zillion trivial commits.

You can always commit a "WIP" (Work-In-Progress) on a dedicated draft branch, where you `git push --force` every time you need to store said work-in-progress.

Regarding the error message, check *all* the settings with `git config -l --show-origin`.
Make sure to upgrade first [to 2.19.1](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.19.1.windows.1) and see if the issue persists. ([PR 1645](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/pull/1645) was somehow related to this error)

Comment: On machineA, it tells me that .gitconfig is stored in c:/users/usernameA... so this is  finally a clue.

Comment: I added a folder with the same username and copied the .gitconfig.  Kinda kludgey, but it moved the error elsehwere.  Now `.git/config` shows the local drive name in the `worktree option` under `[core]`.  I won't try to mess with that.

Answer (score 0):

You store your code under c:\users\username. Move it outside this path (you can use mklink /j to link it to c:\users\username to get it synced). Git uses absolute paths sometime and those abs paths are different on machineA and machineB.

Comment: So strictly speaking, the code on the left is in `c:\users\usernameA\onedrive\companyname\dev\clojure\projectname` with a symlink to `c:\dev`.  On the right it's the same with usernameB and a symlink to `c:\kdev`.  I work exclusively in the `c:\dev` and `c:\kdev` linked directories, but the error still refers to the user's home directory where Onedrive likes to live.  I'll dig around some more to see if I can find how git may encode originating repository's username.